# Black screen after boot on a raspberry Pi 3 model B

Tags: pi-3, boot-issues

so I have been running my Pi for a few moments already and after storage time, tried to boot it and it would do everything normally, but after displaying the "welcome to raspberry Pi desktop" screen, there is a black screen.

The keyboard is reactive, so doing ctrl+alt+delete will cause it to reboot, there previously was a lightning bolt on the top right, I changed the power adapter and it went away.

The green light flashes normally

edit: I am using raspbian
I can't figure out what causes the problem, thanks for helping!

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I suggest you re-flash your sd card with the latest Raspbian Buster with Desktop.

Comment: I tried, but can't seem to get Pi imager to work, every time I press sd card, it crashes, I'll look into that